# Android - removing layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity that makes a layout programmatically from a Shared Preference using a for loop. The text views and buttons are enclosed in a linear layout. The user can input as many views as he wants. Now, the button will be a delete button. When pressed, I want to delete the linear layout the button and the other textviews are contained. How do I do this?

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
package com.dirkjan.myschools;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout subjectLeft, subjectRight;

Button addSubj;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    subjectLeft = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSubjectLeft);
    subjectRight = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSubjectRight);

    //Load the saved subjects
    SharedPreferences getSubjects = getSharedPreferences("SubjectInfo_Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSubjects.edit();

    int subjectCount = getSubjects.getInt("count", 0);
    if (subjectCount > 0 ){
        for (int i = 1; i <= subjectCount; i++){
            //Set the linear layout for each subject
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            //SET BOTTOM MARGIN
            float margin = 5; //RESIZE MARGIN HERE!
            int margs = (int) (margin * scale + 0.5f);

            //SET PADDING IN DP
            float padding = 5; //RESIZE PADDING HERE!
            int pads = (int) (padding * scale +0.5f);
            llParams.setMargins(0,0,0,margs);

            //SETTING THE LINEARLAYOUT PARAMS
            ll.setLayoutParams(llParams);
            ll.setPadding(pads, pads, pads, pads);

            //SETTING THE BACKGROUND COLOR OF THE LINEAR LAYOUT
            String chosenColor = getSubjects.getString("chosenColor" + i, "BLUE");

            if (chosenColor.equals("Green")){
                ll.setBackgroundResource(R.color.HoloGreen);
            }else if (chosenColor.equals("Blue")){
                ll.setBackgroundResource(R.color.HoloBlue);
            }else if (chosenColor.equals("Gray")){
                ll.setBackgroundResource(R.color.HoloGray);
            }else if (chosenColor.equals("Orange")){
                ll.setBackgroundResource(R.color.HoloOrange);
            }else {
                ll.setBackgroundResource(R.color.HoloYellow);
            }

            //ADDING THE LAYOUT TO THE APPROPRIATE CONTAINER (LEFT OR RIGHT)
            if (i % 2 == 1){
                subjectLeft.addView(ll);
            } else {
                subjectRight.addView(ll);
            }

            //SETTING THE SUBJECT NAME TEXTVIEW
            TextView SubjectName = new TextView(this);
            SubjectName.setText(getSubjects.getString("subjectName" + i, "Error"));
            SubjectName.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            SubjectName.setTextSize(22);
            SubjectName.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            //SETTING THE SUBJECT NUMB TEXT VIEW
            TextView SubjectNumber = new TextView(this);
            SubjectNumber.setText(getSubjects.getString("subjectNumb" + i, "Error"));
            SubjectNumber.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            SubjectNumber.setTextSize(16);

            //Creating the divider line
            ImageView divider = new ImageView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams dividerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2);
            divider.setLayoutParams(dividerParams);
            divider.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Black);

            //Add Views into the Layout
            ll.addView(SubjectNumber);
            ll.addView(SubjectName);
            ll.addView(divider);
        }



    }

    addSubj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlusSubject);
    addSubj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent toAddSubj = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    AddSubjectActivity.class);
            startActivity(toAddSubj);
            finish();
        }
    });
}






@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Please do take note that no id is assigned for each layout. It would help if there is a code to identify the parent of the  parent of the button (The button is in a relative layout, which is in a linear layout where the linear layout must be removed by clicking the button.

Comment: `The button is in a relative layout, which is in a linear layout where the linear layout must be removed by clicking the button` so you want to remove the parent layout by clicking on a child view? Then what about the child views of that parent layout?

Comment: They will all be deleted together with the parent layout.

Answer (score 18):

First find your parent layout using

```
ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_linearlayout);
```

get the child layout using

```
final LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout) ll.findViewById(count);
```

now to remove the whole layout you can use `removeview()` method as below

```
ll.removeView(child);
```

to only remove all views from the particular layout(here for eg. child) you can use

```
child.removeAllViews();
```

Comment: I did not assign an id to the child I want to remove. How can I do this without needing to assign an id for each layout since this should be done programmatically?

Comment: What is count here ?

Comment: you can get no of childs in partucular layout by using `ll.getChildCount()`;

Answer (score 14):

You can call `view.setVisiblility(View.GONE)` if you want to remove it from the layout, or `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` if you just want to hide it.

Comment: This hides the view, but doesn't remove it from the stack.

Answer (score 5):

You can remove a Child View from a parent by calling removeView(View view), for example like this :

```
parent.removeView(child);
```

Comment: Yes, but how will I remove it without the id assigned for everything. The layouts and views are created programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

Supposing that your LinearLayout ID is my_linear_layout, just do this in your onClickListener:

```
 findViewById(R.id.my_linear_layout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

In your XML, be sure to put the ID:

```
 <LinearLayout 
      android:id="@+id/my_linear_layout"
      ...>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There is no id assigned to the linear layout since the layout is added programmatically.

Comment: In this case, you can directly do `ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: How will the app know that ll is the parent layout where the button is contained?

Comment: The method will apply to the `LinearLayout` and all its children.

Comment: What I mean is, there are many linear layouts. And in each linear layout, there is a relative layout where the button is contained. And there is no ID assigned on the layouts, views and buttons. How will I set the `onCLickListener()` ?

Comment: I see. Your problem is more complex than I first thought. Maybe you can put your LinearLayouts in a List (ArrayList for instance). Then I guess you'll be able to get it from your button. Could you post the code of your two XML files please?

Comment: The XML files are not needed, i guess. Because the layouts are created programmatically. The info per layout and textview are stored and fetched from a Shared Preference.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like get the id of the currently clicked item
and assigned in root layout

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
```

And remove using this code given below:

```
linearLayout.removeView(layout);
```

Comment: The variable `v` does not seem to appear in the OP's question.

Comment: yes I am giving the example,v is the view in onclick(View v).you can access element using "v" to get their ids